# How to use ListView inside of ContentDialog

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to use a ContentDialog by "HardCode" not in XAML page,i have a lot TextBlocks to use so, maybe i need to use a ScrollView or ListView inside of ContentDialog,this is my Code!

```cs
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Text = "TI Cajueiro Seco / Rua do Sol";
            txt.FontSize = 25;
            txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            txt.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            txt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("/Fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLD.OTF#Myriad Pro");

TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
            txt2.Text = "Rotas da Linha";
            txt2.FontSize = 25;
            txt2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            txt2.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txt2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            txt2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("/Fonts/Exo-Regular.ttf#Exo");

Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Children.Add(txt2);
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 

StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
            //stk.Children.Add(bar);
            stk.Children.Add(txt);
            stk.Children.Add(espaco);
            stk.Children.Add(grid);
            //stk.Children.Add(txt3);
            stk.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;

Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
            contentGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            contentGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;  
            contentGrid.Width -= 40;
            contentGrid.Children.Add(stk);

ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog();
              dlg.Content = contentGrid;
              SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
              color.Opacity = 0.9;
              dlg.Background = color;
              dlg.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: It would be fairly simple, add your contentGrid to ScrollViewer and and than set your scrollViewer as content of your content dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need a *ListView* in this case. The most simple case it would be to define it completely in XAML, but of course it's possible to do it in code.

```xml
<!-- first DataTemplate for your items -->
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myResourceTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25"/> <!--also rest of properties font-size etc.-->
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<!-- define your dialog in xaml -->
<ContentDialog x:Name="myXAMLDialog">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="myXAMLList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myResourceTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

Then in code:

```cs
// your list with strings somewhere
ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "First", "Second", "Third" };

private async void firstBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myXAMLList.ItemsSource = strings;
    await myXAMLDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

And below the same almost completely in code:

```cs
private async void secondBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog myDlg = new ContentDialog();
    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    ListView myList = new ListView();
    myList.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["myResourceTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    myList.ItemsSource = strings;
    myGrid.Children.Add(myList);
    myDlg.Content = myGrid;
    await myDlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

In both above cases, all you need is to set a source for items in *ListView*, it will create items basing on the *DataTemplate* itself.

As you may take a look how *ListView* works - it's pretty much the same - stackpanel with a scrollveiwer.

Comment: The list view isn't scrolling :/

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Have you tried to define height of your panel and/or dialog?

Comment: I did. I also tried wrapping the contents of the contentdialog in a scrollviewer and sizing that. The list doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Put *Grid* inside your *ContentDialog* and bind its *Height* to for example LayoutRoot's (standard grid) actualheight - as I've tried, should do the job: `Height="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualHeight}"`.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either :/ - I have this question open on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496568/scrollviewer-keeps-snapping-back-to-top?noredirect=1#comment50971473_31496568)

Comment: Using that example, I figured it out. I had to add another grid to my outermost grid and call that LayoutRoot, then add a grid inside of the content dialog and bind that to LayoutRoot. I have no idea why this works, but thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Anyone coming here looking for a way to have a Scrollable ListView inside a ContentDialog in a Windows 10 Universal project, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9112c2fe-1d93-48c9-9638-815be8005b86/uwpwindows-10-uap-scrollviewer-in-contentdialog?forum=wpdevelop#454182b6-e609-4be9-b5be-a464ed13f791).  Basically there's a slight modification that needs to be made to the ContentDialog template.  You can paste in the modified version from that answer, then apply that template to your ContentDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English! 
My implementation ListView inside ContentDialog with scrolling. Scrolling listview items running.

1. Add ListView item template

   ```
   private DataTemplate Create()
   {
       var stringReader = new StringReader(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
       <TextBlock TextWrapping=""Wrap"" HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch""
          VerticalAlignment=""Stretch"" Text=""{Binding Title}"" FontSize=""14""/>
          </DataTemplate>");

       return XamlReader.Load(stringReader.ReadToEnd()) as DataTemplate;
   }
   ```
2. ListView

   ```
    var myList = new ListView
       {
           ItemTemplate = Create(),
           ItemsSource =
              new ObservableCollection<Str>()
               {
                   new Str() {Id =1, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =2, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =3, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =4, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =5, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =6, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =7, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =8, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =9, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =10, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =11, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =12, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =13, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =14, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =15, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =16, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =17, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =18, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =19, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =20, Title = "test"},
                   new Str() {Id =21, Title = "test5000"}
               },
           HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
           VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,

       };
   ```
3. Create ScrollViewer

   ```
    var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
    var height = bounds.Height;
    var scroll = new ScrollViewer() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, Height = height - 100 };
   ```
4. Add ListView and ScrollViewer in ContentDialog

   ```
    var grid = new StackPanel();
    grid.Children.Add(myList);
    scroll.Content = grid;
    var dialog = new ContentDialog { Title = "Title", Content = scroll };
    var s = dialog.ShowAsync();
   ```
5. Implementation of the dialog is closed by clicking on the item

   ```
       myList.SelectionChanged += delegate (object o, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
       {
           var item = ((ListView)o).SelectedItem;
           s.Cancel();
       };
   ```

Comment: This may very well be a solution to the question at hand, but code only answers are not accepted on SO, they should always come with some explanation as to why and how the code works. Thanks!