# ScrollViewer keeps snapping back to top

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

So I have this user control that contains a ListView, wrapped by a ScrollViewer. I set up my layout in the DataTemplate and it's displaying fine, but when you try to scroll down, it just snaps back to the top; it won't hold its position.

Here is the xaml:

```
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="80" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Rectangle>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DefaultText}" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultText}" Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DefaultText}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Cost}" Width="100" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I saw another post suggesting that the problem is that the ScrollViewer is larger than the grid inside the item template. First of all, that sounds silly, so if I'm just using scrollviewer wrong, please just let me know how to fix that. Secondly, when I take the advice I saw in the article (set the height of the inner grid to be larger than the height of the scrollviewer), what happens is the height of every list item ends up being the height of the grid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of a ListView in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: The list wasn't scrolling when there were a lot of items

Comment: What was holding the list before you put it in the ScrollViewer (outer panel)?

Comment: Just the default grid

Comment: Something is wrong then. Was it in a row that has Height set to Auto perhaps?

Comment: The grid had no definitions. It was just being used as a container. Bear in mind this is a user control and this user control is being displayed in a dialog.

Comment: So I copy-pasted this xaml into a new window and loaded the items and it worked fine. I guess this means it has something to do with the fact that's being displayed in a dialog

Comment: Keep in Mind: ListView has an own Scrollviewer and will have infinite size, so you loose all data virtualization capabilities.